# Connecting to a MacOS sandboxed application through a DOMAIN socket from a non-sandboxed application

Tags: macos, sockets, finder

I'm consulting for a company building a cross-platform application. This is a WPF and Xamarin.Mac cross-platform project. Managers typically tend to underestimate the difficulty of doing the "port" to Mac. I did look at other answers but the scenarios are not quite the same.

They are building a file sync application that is similar in some respects to DropBox and others. We must connect the Xamarin.Mac app (based on .Net Core) with a native MacOS "Finder Extension" that must run in a sandbox. .Net Core employs a unix "domain socket" under the hood in the unix implementation as their major communication mechanism, even to implement pipes. This is fine for most things, but requires a virtual file to live in a well-known location to be accessed by the socket infrastructure on both ends. The problem is that the sandboxed app (the finder extension) can't access this file in a directory outside its sandbox, even with absolute path read/write entitlements. That entitlement does not make it OK to put a socket's virtual file there, apparently. Everything works fine in a test program that is NOT sandboxed, so we believe the interaction with .Net Core is being done correctly. I receive IPC connection error messages in the system log when we ask the sandboxed app to access the socket. And otherwise the operation silently fails. The way around this is to employ an un-sandboxed intermediary app that communicates with .Net through a socket (works fine)  and communicates with the finder extension through the Notification system (also works fine). Before I go and do this, I thought I'd ask if any body has a fix that I don't know about. When I solve this, I'll share it here, of course, if it's something arcane. Not sure if it's OK to include this in the same question, but we seem to have problems monitoring file status on Documents, Pictures, Movies and  the other standard personal folders.